# How to create database connection loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, etl

How can I create a database loop in python (pandas).
For example, I have multiple database connections.
How can I execute one query in each database

db connection file

```
        db1 = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://login:pass@host:1433/db1')
    db2 = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://login:pass@host:1433/db2')
db3 = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://login:pass@host:1433/db3')
```

pandas file

```
c1_engine = db1
    pd1 = pd.read_sql(
    """select * from table """,
    c1_engine)
    pd1.to_sql('table2', con=dwh_engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem .

```
db = {'db1':create_engine('mssql+pymssql://login:pass@host:1433/db1'),
          'db2':create_engine('mssql+pymssql://login:pass@host:1433/db2')}
for engine in db.values():
...
```